# Passing state mapped to props in redux w/ React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm trying to map state to props in a root component and pass down the props to all children components. Here's what I have so far.

```
index.js

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router children={routes} history={history} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

.

```
root.js

class Root extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { user, fetchLogin } = this.props

    return (
      <div id="root root-dev">
        <h1>tsuyoku app</h1>
        <LoginStatus user={user} fetchLogin={fetchLogin} />
        <hr />
        <DevTools />
        <div {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  userActions
)(Root)
```

.

```
home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props) // only has router props
    let { user } = this.props // undefined

    return (
      <div id="home-page">
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my root.js is correctly mapping state to props, and when I pass specific props to `<LoginStats />` it works. however, when I try to pass all props via `<div {...this.props} />` the props are not available in `<Home />`. the component renders, just doesn't have all the props.

Edit: Instead of passing `{...this.props}` to a div, in react-router 1.0+ you have to use

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Provider` in the top level component that your router returns. Or, use the new `render` prop in react-router 2.0 https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#routingcontext---router-render-prop